# Is there a way to redirect a domain with a slug to a new domain with a new slug on Namecheap?

Tags: domains, redirects, dns, namecheap, url-slug

So I'm no expert with domain directs, so forgive me if this is a dumb question, but here we go:

What we want to do is direct our site's blog posts from our old site (with old root domain and slug) to our new domain and new slug. For example:

`sitea.example/slug1` ***redirects to*** `siteb.example/different-slug`

I can only find a way to redirect our site's root domain on Namecheap. So I've already redirected `sitea.example` to `siteb.example`. The problem lies with directing a domain with a slug.

Do I have to create a CNAME record or something for each redirect?

Comment: Can you configure your new server to do the slug redirects.  For example `sitea.example/slug1` would redirect to `siteb.example/slug1` which would finally redirect to `siteb.example/different-slug`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by "configure your new server to do slug redirects". We are registered with namecheap for our old domain, and with google domains for our new domain? And I think we have to set up the redirects from the place that owns our old domain. Are you saying transfer the old domain ownership to google domains? Would that work? Thanks for your answer

Comment: It really doesn't matter where your domain is registered.  What matters is how it is hosted.  It sounds like you are using very simple redirect hosting for your old domain.  How is your new domain hosted?

Comment: So we can only redirect domain names with slugs/extensions from the hosting website such as squarespace, wix, etc (for example)? Our old website is hosted on webflow, and so is our new website (both webflow). They are two different projects on webflow, and are each connected to their respective domain. I know I can redirect domains with slugs from the old website's webflow project, but then we would have to keep paying for that project, right?

Comment: I am suggesting that you use a  simple redirect hosting service (like from namecheap) for your old domain that redirects every path to the same exact path on the new domain.  And then in your hosting for the new domain (on webflow), configure redirects for all the old URL slugs.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can redirect pages from your old site to a new URL in Namecheap's DNS management section.

> Select URL Redirect Record from the drop-down menu for Type, put the
> host to be forwarded to the Host line (@ for your root domain, i.e.,
> domain.com, www for [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com), * for a wildcard record), and
> enter the destination URL into the Value line:

https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/385/2237/how-to-redirect-a-url-for-a-domain/

Comment: Practically speaking, when it comes to HTTP(s) you cant use DNS to manipulate paths - only mapping from domains to IP addresses.  I believe that this answer is wrong. (Also, it only covers HTTP, not HTTPS)

Comment: The question was specific to Namecheap or I would have said to use regex and htaccess. It says that in the linked article btw. 

They didn't say anything about https or http only asked if they could redirect a page using Namecheap's control panel. Yes, possible. Advisable? Probably not, and they are a beginner so I assume they want to use the Namecheap control panel.